# Value.match(/[^0-9|\/]/gi) is not working for numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex, match, expression

```
if (value.match(/[^0-9|\/]/gi)) {
   super.setValue(this.value, { ...options, emitModelToViewChange: true });
   return;
}
```

Why this **value.match** is not working?

This is copied from a tutorial and for the instructor its working fine.

It shoul be true, if I enter a **number** or **'/'** into the input, but in my case this if-statement will never be executed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In regex, ^ denotes NOT. You have put a NOT on the range 0-9 or '/'. Your current regex would return true for an alphabet. Remove ^ and try this:

```
if (value.match(/[0-9|\/]/gi)) {
   super.setValue(this.value, { ...options, emitModelToViewChange: true });
   return;
}
```

This should return true for a number or '/'. /[^**[0-9]**|/]/gi would give true for '/' but not for number.

Answer (score 0):

`[^0-9]` Matches any characters except those in the range 0-9

```js
// E.g.

"9".match(/[^0-9|\/]/g) // null
"9".match(/[^0-5|\/]/g) // ["9"]
```